# PHP and mysqli: Upload blob to database using form

Tags: php, html, mysqli, blob

I'm trying to upload an image into a database as a blob using PHP with mysqli.  If I just try to insert the image name using a query, it works just fine and a new row with the name is created (blob is null).  Once I start trying to upload the blob via a form into the database using a query and jquery functions, a new row is created, but the blob shows 0 B.  The first bit of code is the html form.  The second is the php file that is called once the form is submitted.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

**Clarification:** I understand that uploading an image to a directory is a more efficient way to store it. In the interests of understanding how to use other options, I am trying to figure out how using blob works.

**EDIT**

Just to clarify I also tried the following snippet of code.

```
if ($filetype == "image/jpeg" && $filesize > 0 && $filesize < 1048576) {
        echo "Import of photo success";

        $aimage = file_get_contents($tmpfile);

        if (!($stmt=$mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO actor_info (aname, aimage) VALUE (?,?)"))) {
            echo "Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ")" . $mysqli->error;
        }

        if (!$stmt->bind_param("sb", $_POST['aname'], $aimage)) {
            echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $stmt->errno .") " . $stmt->error;
        }

        if (!$stmt->execute()) {
            echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
        }

        else {
            printf("%d row inserted.<br/>", $stmt->affected_rows);
        }
    }
```

**END EDIT**

**Error Messages**

Import of photo success
Notice: Undefined index: aimage in /nfs/stak/students/m/martalic/public_html/CS494/Test/addActorInfo.php on line 43

Warning: file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: Filename cannot be empty in /nfs/stak/students/m/martalic/public_html/CS494/Test/addActorInfo.php on line 43
1 row inserted

**HTML FORM**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form" method="post" action=addActorInfo.php enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Actor Name: <input id="aname" type="text" name="aname" class="required" maxlength="64"><br><br>
    Attach Photo: <input id="aimage" type="file" name="aimage" class="required"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="ADD" value="ADD"/>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**PHP**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
Actor Information
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$mysqli = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}

if(isset( $_POST["ADD"]) ) {
    $aname = $_POST['aname'];
    $errorinfo = $_FILES["aimage"]["error"];
    $filename = $_FILES["aimage"]["name"];
    $tmpfile = $_FILES["aimage"]["tmp_name"];
    $filesize = $_FILES["aimage"]["size"];
    $filetype = $_FILES["aimage"]["type"];

    if (!($filetype == "image/jpeg" && $filesize > 0)) {
        echo "Import of photo failed";
    }

    if ($filetype == "image/jpeg" && $filesize > 0 && $filesize < 1048576) {
        echo "Import of photo success";

        if (!($stmt=$mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO actor_info (aname, aimage) VALUE (?,?)"))) {
            echo "Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ")" . $mysqli->error;
        }
        $null = NULL;
        if (!$stmt->bind_param("sb", $_POST['aname'], $null)) {
            echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $stmt->errno .") " . $stmt->error;
        }

        if (!$stmt->send_long_data(0, file_get_contents($_POST['aimage']))) {
            echo "Did not get contents";
        }

        if (!$stmt->execute()) {
            echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
        }

        else {
            printf("%d row inserted.<br/>", $stmt->affected_rows);
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "Image must be under 1 MB";
    }
    $stmt->close();
}
$mysqli->close();
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you not considered uploading the image like you do, but then placing it in a folder /uploadedimg/ and then referencing the filename (randomly generated) and inserting that into the db? BLOB is not really efficient.

So upload. Name file. Save file. Reference file in db as imgName = myfile123.png and then when you need it just use that

```
$myvar = $SQLQuery;

<img src="/uploadedimg/". $myvar ." " alt="my image" />
```

Comment: Absolutely.  I'm trying the blob to get the hang of how it works.

Comment: Well forget the BLOB thing, looks like you have the code correct for the upload, just note where you upload it and place the name of the file as a VARCHAR into the db. Don't let BLOB get you down.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I am interested in learning how blob works for uploading and storing.  I may or may not ever use it again, but at least I'll understand its pros and cons because I've tried it.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem in my binding parameters.  By switching from "b" to "s", I was able to store the image as a blob in my database.